# Receiving messages as ASCII String with KafkaListener

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka

I am using the KafkaListener interface of the Spring Framework to listen to a Kafka topic. The code is working, but I am receiving the messages in a ASCII String I guess. I am not quite sure why this is the case.

Here is my code:

```
 import org.slf4j.Logger; 
 import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory; 
 import org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaListener;
 import org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.Payload;
 import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

 @Service 
 public class Receiver {
     private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Receiver.class);

     @KafkaListener(topics = "mongoDBTest", groupId = "test")
     public void listen(@Payload String cMessage) {
         LOG.info("received message=" + cMessage);
         Application.print();
    } 
}
```

When consuming e.g. "test", I am getting "received message=116,101,115,116" as output.

Comment: Tell us more about the producer & consumer configs/factories.

Answer (score 0):

Hi it looks like someone consumes messages in a wrong way instead of just String. If you can fix it on that part - that's awesome.

Otherwise you'll need to decode these bytes to normal String. 
Please try

```
String[] split = cMessage.split(",");
byte[] bytes = new byte[split.length];
for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
    bytes[i] = Byte.parseByte(split[i]);
}
LOG.info("received message=" + new String(bytes));
```